# VBA function to convert name format

Tags: vba, excel

I want to take a name in First Last format and change it to Last, First.  I know I could to this with a formula but I want to be complicated.

Please let me know if you see any red flags in my code, or suggestions for improvements.

```
Function LastFirst(Name_FL As String)
'This only works if there is a single space in the cell - Will Error If Spaces <> 1

Length = Len(Name_FL) 'Establishes Length of String

Spaces = Length - Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Name_FL, " ", "")) 'Number of spaces

If Spaces <> 1 Then
    LastFirst = "#SPACES!#" 'Error Message
Else
    SpaceLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", Name_FL, 1) 'Location of space
    Last = Right(Name_FL, Length - SpaceLocation) 'Establishes Last Name String
    First = Left(Name_FL, SpaceLocation) 'Establishes First Name String
    LastFirst = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Last & ", " & First) 'Puts it together
End If

End Function 'Ta-da
```

Comment: "let me know if you see any suggestions" - What's your question here? Does your code work? If not, what value does it provide vs what you expect/desire? If it does, what are you trying to improve?

Comment: As a general note, if you are developing VBA code, you should use the application.worksheetfunction method only when there are no available similar functions in VBA. So I understand what you're trying to do, because you are likely familiar with the Excel function equivilents, but if you are doing this to develop your VBA skills, those Excel functions can be a crutch. You should be looking to expand your knowledge on available VBA functions instead. This will give you greater flexibility as you will not be relying on the limited set of functions from Excel.

Comment: I works, but I wanted to know if there was a way to be more efficient. Or provide a better outcome.  I also wanted to provide this for anyone who might have the same need.  

Thanks for the tip about not using application.worksheetfunction as a crutch.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it to:

```
Function LastFirst(Name_FL As String) As String

If (Len(Name_FL) - Len(Replace(Name_FL, " ", ""))) > 1 Then
    LastFirst = "#SPACES#"
Else
    LastFirst = StrConv(Split(Name_FL, " ")(1) & ", " & Split(Name_FL, " ")(0), vbProperCase)
End If

End Function
```

The logic here is:

- If there is more than 1 space, return the error string `#SPACES#`
- If there is 1 space, the split the string using `" "` as a delimiter.
- Use the second index of the Split array, add `", "` and use the first index of the split array.
- Use `StrConv()` to convert it all to proper case.

  ---

You might also want to add another check for **no** spaces:

```
If InStr(Name_FL, " ") > 0 Then
    '// There is a space in the string
Else
    '// There is no space in the string
End If
```

Which can also be tested for by slightly changing the logic of the above example:

```
Function LastFirst(Name_FL As String) As String

If (Len(Name_FL) - Len(Replace(Name_FL, " ", ""))) = 1 Then
    LastFirst = StrConv(Split(Name_FL, " ")(1) & ", " & Split(Name_FL, " ")(0), vbProperCase)
Else
    LastFirst = "#SPACES#"
End If

End Function
```

---

***Further elaboration on functions:***

You can see I've used some VBA functions here in place of your `WorksheetFunction` methods.

- `Len()` returns the **Len**gth of a string.
- `Replace()` does what it says on the tin - replaces a given string with another.
- `StrConv()` **Conv**erts a **Str**ing to a respective case (e.g. `vbProperCase`).
- `Split()` Creates a zero-based single dimension array from a string, by **Split**ting it on a given delimiter.

Finally - Don't forget to specify a return value in your function header:

`Function LastFirst(Name_FL As String)`**`As String`**`<~~ return type`

Comment: @Learn2Shoot This is what I meant when I said you should look for VBA functions instead of regular Excel functions - you can see how much cleaner the code is by using VBA's Split function instead of defining all your variables for length, and then using Right/Left.

Comment: @MacroMan 
Thank you this is what I was looking for.  I need to spend some time learning the native functions of VBA.

I went with this initially but I like the other method too



`If (Len(Name_FL) - Len(Replace(Name_FL, " ", ""))) <> 1 Then`

Comment: @learn2shoot Not a problem - don't forget to mark as the answer if it helped (green tick on the left)